# ClassCastException of LayoutParams to MarginLayoutParams after setting a view's width

Tags: android-layout

I've written a small proxy class so that I can use ObjectAnimator to animate a view's margin. After checking that this worked and everything animated properly, I wanted to adjust the view's size before the animation, but after I set the width, my animation fails with the ClassCastException. I haven't a clue why.

```
private class handleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int LEFT_MARGIN_VISIBLE = 0;
    private static final int LEFT_MARGIN_HIDDEN = -196;

    public void onClick(View view) {
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
        RelativeLayout options = (RelativeLayout) row.findViewById(R.id.options);
        LayoutProxy layoutProxy = new LayoutProxy(options);

        // First make sure the options are the right width to fill the screen with the handle
        int rowWidth = row.getWidth();
        int handleWidth = view.getWidth();
        layoutProxy.setWidth(rowWidth - handleWidth);
        ObjectAnimator animation;

        if (layoutProxy.getLeftMargin() == Util.dipsToPixels(options, LEFT_MARGIN_VISIBLE)) {
            animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(layoutProxy, "leftMargin", Util.dipsToPixels(view, LEFT_MARGIN_VISIBLE), Util.dipsToPixels(view, LEFT_MARGIN_HIDDEN)); 
        } else {
            animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(layoutProxy, "leftMargin", Util.dipsToPixels(view, LEFT_MARGIN_HIDDEN), Util.dipsToPixels(view, LEFT_MARGIN_VISIBLE)); 
        }

        animation.setDuration(200);
        animation.start();
    }

    /**
     * Allows an ObjectAnimator to set/get margins and dimensions of a view
     */
    private class LayoutProxy {
        private ViewGroup mView;

        public LayoutProxy(View view) {
            mView = (ViewGroup) view;
        }

        public int getWidth() {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.width;
        }

        public void setWidth(int width) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
            mView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, lp.height));
        }

        public int getHeight() {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.height;
        }

        public void setHeight(int height) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
            mView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lp.width, height));
        }

        public int getLeftMargin() {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.leftMargin;
        }

        public void setLeftMargin(int margin) {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(margin, lp.topMargin, lp.rightMargin, lp.bottomMargin);
            mView.requestLayout();
        }

        public int getTopMargin() {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.topMargin;
        }

        public void setTopMargin(int margin) {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(lp.leftMargin, margin, lp.rightMargin, lp.bottomMargin);
            mView.requestLayout();
        }

        public int getRightMargin() {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.rightMargin;
        }

        public void setRightMargin(int margin) {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(lp.leftMargin, lp.topMargin, margin, lp.bottomMargin);
            mView.requestLayout();
        }

        public int getBottomMargin() {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            return lp.bottomMargin;
        }

        public void setBottomMargin(int margin) {
            MarginLayoutParams lp = (MarginLayoutParams) mView.getLayoutParams();
            lp.setMargins(lp.leftMargin, lp.topMargin, lp.rightMargin, margin);
            mView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
at com.test.data.ContactListCursorAdapter$handleClickListener$LayoutProxy.getLeftMargin(ContactListCursorAdapter.java:135)
at com.test.data.ContactListCursorAdapter$handleClickListener.onClick(ContactListCursorAdapter.java:94)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
```

Comment: I've also tried setting the width without the use of the layoutProxy and casting still fails after that.

Comment: Can you show us which LayoutParams you have imported

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have similar problem

At first I was using:

```
LayoutParams viewFlowLayout = new LayoutParams(originalWidth, newHeight);
viewFlow.setLayoutParams(flowViewLayout);
```

And I have the same error message as yours:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams
```

which I have no idea why as i didn't use MarginLayoutParams.

Then I try and change it to this

```
LayoutParams viewFlowLayout = viewFlow.getLayoutParams();
viewFlowLayout.height = newheight;
viewFlow.setLayoutParams(flowViewLayout);
```

And the error disappear...

---

I guess you have multiple use case for the above code.
For example: Change this

```
public void setHeight(int height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
    mView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lp.width, height));
}
```

to

```
public void setHeight(int height) {
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mView.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = height  //width will remain and height will be change to the newHeight
    mView.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

Hope that it will be helpful to you and many people out there...

Answer (score -1):

I just want to know the reason why you are casting LayoutParams to MarginLayoutParams. Is there a specific reason? Because i think the problem lies there.

Comment: LaoutParams does not hold Margin information, only MarginLayoutParams.  Is there another way to access margins that I missed?

Comment: LayoutParams does hold margin information. You can access it like this:
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        params.leftMargin = //some interger

Comment: @STT That's how you can set the margins, not get them :)

Comment: -1 This should a comment. Please learn how to use StackOverflow. Do you actually think this helps the community? C'mon... This is basic.